# What is the alternative way of PostConstruct annotation?

Tags: java, spring, csv, spring-batch, aws-batch

First of all, thank you for visiting my post.

I have a Spring Batch Project that is using tasklet and chunk.
The chunk aka step1 is where I am processing data and generate a new csv file in the s3 bucket.
The tasklet aka step2 is where I am reading the csv file from s3 bucket that was generated in step1 and sending SNS topic.

Right now, I have a problem with the SNSTopicSender class that implements Tasklet.
first of all, here are the config class and SNSTopicSender class.

```
@Bean
Step step1() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step1")
                .<BadStudent, BadStudent>chunk(100)
                .reader(new IteratorItemReader<Student>(this.StudentLoader.Students.iterator()) as ItemReader<? extends BadStudent>)
                .processor(this.studentProcessor as ItemProcessor<? super BadStudent, ? extends BadStudent>)
                .writer(this.csvWriter())
                .build()
}

@Bean
Step step2() {
    return this.stepBuilderFactory
                .get("step2")
                .tasklet(new PublishSnsTopic())
                .build()
}

@Bean
Job job() {
    return this.jobBuilderFactory
                .get("scoring-students-batch")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(this.step1())
                .next(this.step2())
                .build()
}
```

```
@Configuration
@Service
class SNSTopicSender implements Tasklet {

    @Autowired
    ResourceLoader resourceLoader

    List<BadStudent> badStudents

    @Autowired
    FileProperties fileProperties

    @PostConstruct
    void setup() {

        String badStudentCSVFileName = "s3://students/failedStudents.csv"
        Reader badStudentReader = new InputStreamReader(
                this.resourceLoader.getResource(badStudentCSVFileName).inputStream
        )

        // create message body and call the publishTopic function
    }

    void publishTopic(SnsClient snsClient, String message, String arn) {
        // sending a topic
    }

    @Override
    RepeatStatus execute(StepContribution contribution, ChunkContext chunkContext) throws Exception {
        return RepeatStatus.FINISHED
    }
}
```

I used `@PostConstruct` because without it, `resoruceLoader and fileProperties` will be null as it would not have `Injection of bean` as you know.
To work around it, I used `@PostConstruct`.

However, I recently realized that SNSTopicSender class is not reading the csv file just created, but it is reading the csv file that was already there before this batch job ran. Because the `@PostConstruct` gets fired before step1 gets completed.(where the target csv file is created).

Then if I removed the `@PostConstruct`, then `resourceLoader and fileProperties` will be null, meaning this batch job would not know where the csv file is stored and also how to read it.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: You can always use constructor injection instead. That said, though, it appears you're trying to store _per-operation state_ in the service object, which is asking for all sorts of concurrency problems (you're observing one). The state needs to be passed around explicitly as part of the request.

Comment: I have tried the constructor and did not work. it is still null

Comment: The `execute` method is currently "empty". Why don't you put that code in the `execute` method? After all, that's what the tasklet is supposed to do according to your description.